# facing problem when try to use npm run build

Tags: node.js, npm

when I'm trying to build my react project using npm run build, then shows an error. also, try using yarn build. but a similar error is showing.below is my code,

```
TypeError: MiniCssExtractPlugin is not a constructor
at module.exports (A:\projects\Own Projects\project-listing-site\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js:664:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (A:\projects\Own Projects\project-listing-site\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\build.js:58:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project-listing-site@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project-listing-site@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-01-15T11_10_02_360Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the mini-css-extract-plugin version.
If you are using yarn, change to this in the `package.json` and then run yarn install:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.4.5"
  },
```

Or if you are using npm, run:

```
npm i -D --save-exact mini-css-extract-plugin@2.4.5
```

If none of these work, check other answers on [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11930)